# Speed-up a single task using multi-processing or threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Is it possible to speed up a single task using multi-processing/threading? My gut feeling is that the answer is 'no'. Here is an example of what I mean by a "single task":

```
for i in range(max):
    pick = random.choice(['on', 'off', 'both'])
```

With an argument of 10000000 it takes about 7.9 seconds to complete on my system.

I have a basic grasp of how to use multi-processing and threading for multiple tasks. For example, if I have 10 directories each one containing X number of files that need to be read, I could use create 10 threads.

I suspect that the single task is using only a single process (task manager reports CPU usage is minimal). Is there a way to leverage my other cores in such cases? Or is increasing the CPU/Memory speeds the only way to get faster results?

Comment: multiprocessing can help, multiple threads in one process not that much (keyword: "global interpreter lock" aka "GIL")

Comment: @Michael Butsher: Could you provide an example of how I could break up the code I mentioned using multiprocessing?

Comment: You can read http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/ for an example

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758952/green-threads-and-thread-in-python

Comment: @Michael Butscher: Cool. I will look into Pool.map :)

Comment: if you want all results at once, you could use `result = numpy.random.choice(L, size=max)` or `result = np.take(L, np.random.random_integers(0, len(L)-1, max))`, where `L = ['on', 'off', 'both']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a benchmark of your code with and without multiprocessing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import time

def test1():
    print "for loop with no multiproc: "
    m = 10000000
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(m):
        pick = random.choice(['on', 'off', 'both'])
    print time.time()-t

def test2():
    print "map with no multiproc: "
    m = 10000000
    t = time.time()
    map(lambda x: random.choice(['on', 'off', 'both']), range(m))
    print time.time()-t

def rdc(x):
    return random.choice(['on', 'off', 'both'])

def test3():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    m = 10000000

    print "map with multiproc: "
    t = time.time()

    r = pool.map(rdc, range(m))
    print time.time()-t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1()
    test2()
    test3()
```

And here is the result on my workstation (which is a quadcore):

```
for loop with no multiproc: 
8.31032013893
map with no multiproc: 
9.48167610168
map with multiproc: 
4.94983720779
```

> Is it possible to speed up a single task using multi-processing/threading? My gut feeling is that the answer is 'no'.

well, afaict, the answer is "damn, yes".

> Is there a way to leverage my other cores in such cases? Or is increasing the CPU/Memory speeds the only way to get faster results?

yes, by using multiprocessing. Python can't handle multiple cores by using threading, because of the GIL, but it can rely on your operating system's scheduler to leverage the other cores. Then you can get a *real* improvement on your tasks.

Comment: The answer is "damn, yes" only if you're using a good computer. On my netbook, test3 is slower than test1.

Comment: the answer "damn yes" is dependant on the number of cores your computer has. If you make a pool of processes that has the same number of processes that you got cores, then you will gain from it (given you have more than one core). If you don't it will be the same (the scheduler does not do miracles).

Comment: @zmo: 3:16 might've screamed "Hell, yeah!", but "damn, yes" also works :) Thank you.

Comment: Sweet solution. You don't even have to start and stop the threads yourself.

Comment: Oddly enough, on my machine, with python3, the results are quite different: `for loop with no multiproc: 25.41977310180664 map with no multiproc: 1.0967254638671875e-05 map with multiproc: 11.853065013885498`

Comment: @zmo: Isn't it what I'm saying? So if you don't have more than one core it doesn't speed up anything, it is even *slower*.

Comment: @doukremt indeed, because the `fork()` and the process pool management is quite costy... @NilsWerner I did not test with python3, but it indeed looks there's something weird happening...

Comment: @NilsWerner: In Python 3, map() behaves like itertools.imap() from Python 2, it returns an iterator. Apply `list()` to consume the result, to get Python 2 behavior.